# Using AJAX to compare variable in Ruby and then render a view accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm new to javascript and ruby, and was wondering whether I'm going about this the right way, and how to get the results I want.
I have a view called events\new.html.erb which allows a user to select another user in a collection select:

```
<%= f.collection_select :id,
                                    Customer.where(business_id: current_customer.business_id),
                                    :id,
                                    :full_name,
                                    { prompt: 'Select' },
                                    { id: "colleageselect", onChange: "renderColCal(this)" } %>

<div id = colleaguecal> </div>
```

This triggers a javascript function 'renderColCal' in application.js , I'm sending to ruby the variable colleagueID:

```
function renderColCal(select){

    var colleagueID = select.value ;


    document.getElementById("colleaguecal").innerHTML = "Your colleague's calendar";

    $.ajax({
            url: 'calendars_controller/calendarChange',
            data: (
                'colleagueID=' + $('select').val()
            )
        }
    )
}
```

here is my route:

```
post 'calendars_controller/calendarChange', to: 'calendars_controller#calendarChange'
```

and then in the controller 'calendars_controller' (not the events controller of the events\new view) I am trying to use colleagueID:

```
def calendarChange
    colleagueID = params[:colleagueID]
    colleague = Customer.where(id: :colleagueID )
    @colcalendar = colleague.calendar
    @events = @colcalendar.events

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render '/calendars/_showColleague'} 
    end
  end
```

what I want to do is to be able to render within the `events\new` html the partial `_showColleague`, using the `@events` variable of Ruby. So, every time a user selects a name on the collection select, it renders the selected colleague's calendar view. At the moment I am getting no response using this code. How would I go about doing this please? I am very new and so would appreciate explanations! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "select#id", function(e) {
   $.get("colleagues/"+  + $(this).val() +"/calendars/1");
});

#config/routes.rb
resources :colleagues do 
   resources :calendars #-> url.com/colleagues/:colleague_id/calendars/:id
end

#app/controllers/calendars_controller.rb
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html

   def show
      @colleague = Customer.find params[:colleague_id]
      @calendar  = Calendar.find params[:id] #-> your pattern; not mine
      @events    = @colleague.calendar.events
   end
end

#app/views/calendars/new.js.erb
$(".element").html("<%=j render 'calendars/_showColleague' %>");
```

--

This will allow you to populate your DOM with the returned `partial`, which I believe is your biggest issue right now. There are also some other considerations (since you're new):

1. **Your routes should be [RESTful](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)** (IE should be scoped around the `calendar` object). You've created an out-of-scope route which is against [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).
2. **Your JS should be [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)**. Using JS like you are (especially inline JS) has a habit of getting messed up due to Turbolinks. Wherever possible, put the JS into the [asset pipeline](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).
3. **[`find` = single](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find); [`where` = collection](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where)**. Using `where` is the same as the `WHERE` clause in SQL - it returns multiple records. `Find` always returns a single record; thus:
4. **Read up about [nested routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)**. You're looking to load a `calendar` for a `colleague`; you need to pass both parameters (which you don't do currently).

Comment: ok I have a couple of questions; firstly, in the routes where you have written resources :colleagues, I don't have a colleague model, they are all Customers, so should I put resources :customers do resources :calendars instead? (and also in the jQuery should I $.get (customers/) too? Secondly, why is 'new.js.erb' needed to render the partial? Thanks

Comment: I have implemented your code but nothing is rendering?

Comment: I have looked at the developer tools in internet explorer and it says HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR): GET - http://127.0.0.1:3000/calendars_controller/calendarChange?colleagueID=3

Comment: To answer your question about `colleagues`, you put in your controller `Customer.find params[:colleague_id]` - the routes reflect that

Comment: colleagueID refers to the javascript variable that was created on collection select change, so I shouldn't change my route or I should?

Comment: In that case, you don't need to change your route. You can just pass the value from JS

Comment: ok, I am still getting the problem though, nothing is rendering and IE developer says it can't find GET calendars_controller/calendarChange?colleagueID=[:id]  I am really confused why this is happening

Comment: 1. have you got *that* route set up? 2. You're passing `[:id]` -- it should be parsed from JS, no?

Comment: yes sorry I meant wherever [:id] is is a number like 2. I realised I hadn't deleted my original javascript code, and now I'm not getting the error. However, it is still not rendering anything. Am I missing another step?

Comment: Have you got a public github repo I could look at for it?

Comment: ok I have made one: https://github.com/sarahshuffle/meeting-helper  I haven't included every single file because some are less relevant, but every file that concerns this problem is included.

Comment: hi have you had the chance to look at it yet?

Comment: Sorry got distracted, let me have a look!

Comment: I don't see what the issue is? You're passing the variables you need, the controllers look good - what's the error?

Comment: there is no error, just nothing is happening when I select  user in the collection select. I don't understand how calendars#new is getting called. Once it sends the variable to calendarChange, how does it know to render _showColleague? Shouldn't calendarChange need to render something?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you got confused between 'events\new.html.erb' where the partial needs to be rendered, and 'calendars\new.js.erb' that you said to create?